# Add new option with custom data attributes to serverside processing select2

Tags: ajax, select, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm having a problem with adding new option with custom data attributes in serverside processing select2.

here's my select2 html :

```
<select name="resellerid" id="resellerid" class="form-select rounded "></select>
```

here's the initiation:

```
$('#resellerid').select2({
        theme: 'bootstrap-5',
        placeholder: 'Ketik Untuk Mencari',
        ajax: {
        url: '/api/referensi-list-reseller',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
            results:  $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text             : item.namareseller + ' - ' + item.namatoko,
                        id               : item.id,
                        picture          : item.fotoreseller,
                        diskon           : item.diskon,
                    }
                })
            };
        },
        cache: true
        }
    });
```

here's my backend, I'm using Laravel:

```
public function listreseller(Request $r){
    $data = [];

    if($r->has('q')){
        $search = $r->q;
        $data   = Reseller::select("namareseller","id","fotoreseller", "namatoko", "diskon", "diskondeepublish")
        ->where('namareseller','ILIKE',"%$search%")
        ->orWhere('namatoko','ILIKE',"%$search%")
        ->get();
    }

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

I tried to follow the documentation, but still not working. here's what I tried so far :

```
var data = {
                text             : response[0].namareseller + ' - ' + response[0].namatoko,
                id               : response[0].resellerid,
                picture          : response[0].fotoreseller,
                diskon           : response[0].diskonbiasa,
            };

            var newOption = new Option(data.text, data.id, true, false);
            $('#resellerid').append(newOption).trigger('change');
```

The new option is successfully added to the select2, but the data attributes is not included.

Any help would be appreciated.